# Error copying an Image object to the clipboard

Tags: java, clipboard

I'm trying to put an Image object into the clipboard and I'm getting a weird error.

This is where the problem is happening.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(clipboardObject.data);
try(ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
    ImageIcon img = (ImageIcon) in.readObject();
    ImageTransferable t = new ImageTransferable(img.getImage());
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
            .setContents(t, null);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is my `ImageTransferable` class.

```
static class ImageTransferable implements Transferable
{
    private Image image;

    public ImageTransferable (Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
            throws UnsupportedFlavorException
    {
        if (isDataFlavorSupported(flavor))
        {
            return image;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported (DataFlavor flavor)
    {
        return flavor.equals(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors ()
    {
        return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.imageFlavor };
    }
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

```
java.io.IOException: Registered service providers failed to encode BufferedImage@5f341870: type = 2 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=ff000000 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 2227 height = 2225 #Bands = 4 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0 to image/jpeg
at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.imageToStandardBytesImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.imageToStandardBytes(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WDataTransferer.imageToPlatformBytes(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.translateTransferable(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WDataTransferer.translateTransferable(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.setContentsNative(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.setContents(Unknown Source)
at com.bruhclp.ClipboardManager.setData(ClipboardManager.java:75)
at com.bruhclp.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It's not an error, just the debug info

Note that this exception shown in the console is not actually an error and it is not really thrown from the `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(t, null);` method call.

JPEG in Java does not support transparency now (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8204188), but the copied image is actually compressed to PNG (or some other format maybe) and the clipboard is set properly even with `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` image type. At least it works for me with JDK 14.

So this exception in the console is just a debugging info (I have investigated for hours to understand it and find that it actually works). The answer is in the OpenJDK `sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.setContentsNative(Transferable contents)` method:

```
         for (Long format : formatMap.keySet()) {
            DataFlavor flavor = formatMap.get(format);

            try {
                byte[] bytes = WDataTransferer.getInstance().
                    translateTransferable(contents, flavor, format);
                publishClipboardData(format, bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Fix 4696186: don't print exception if data with
                // javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType failed to serialize.
                // May remove this if-check when 5078787 is fixed.
                if (!(flavor.isMimeTypeEqual(DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType) &&
                      e instanceof java.io.NotSerializableException)) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope that saves someone's time.

Answer (score 1):

Having done some research, it seems that the alpha channel of the JPEG image is no longer supported in the OpenJDK implementation. Therefore you have to convert the image you want to put in the clipboard to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`.

This is how you can do this.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(clipboardObject.data);
try(ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
        ImageIcon img = (ImageIcon) in.readObject();
        Image original =  img.getImage();

        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
                original.getWidth(null), original.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        ImageTransferable t = new ImageTransferable(newImage);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
                .setContents(t, null);
}catch(Exception e)
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```